# Truth table(ish) with wildcards

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

First things first, this is intended for pattern matching so keep that in mind because its possible you might have a completely different solution and I want to hear about it.

I have this series of data (lets call it mystring for now).

```
string a = get_starting_letters(mystring)
string b = get_ending_letters(mystring)
bool c = check_code_appears(mystring)
.
.
.
and so on
```

I would like have a dictionary/truth table that works something like this (* denotes a wildcard).

```
key  (a,b,c...)               value

"abc", *, True     =   "type a string"
"abc", "xyz", True =   "type b string"
*, "xyz", True     =   "type m string"
```

How could this be implemented in C#? I know this is pretty trivial with F# however this code will possibly be updated in the future by people that only know C#.

Why am I doing this? because the current code is becoming hard to follow and update (too many nested if, else, else if) and only a couple of the "types" are described so far (it will double in a couple of months).

Other solutions I've been thinking about: A sort of tree/structure that describes the different possible variables that are checked by the conditions:

```
                      b = "xyz"
           a = "abc" <
mystring <            b = "xxx"
           a = "cda" <
                      b = *
```

However it seems like it would have a big overhead and speed is important for this, additionally the tree would not be binary and require handling wildcards too.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but I'd suggest making your own  class with three keys and a value that implements IList/IDictionary. You'd have to overload equals and some other stuff, but it'd handle your case functionally and would be fast enough for most people's needs (especially if you have few types in the collection). As almost always: Implement first, Optimize Later

Comment: If it's trivial in F#, pair with someone who doesn't know F# and use F#.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need if to be able to check whether a given tuple matches a given type, then you could just use a regular dictionary, like

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, bool>> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, bool>>();

//add some values
lookup["type a string"] = new Tuple<string, string, bool>("abc", null, true);
lookup["type b string"] = new Tuple<string, string, bool>("abc", "xyz", true);
lookup["type m string"] = new Tuple<string, string, bool>(null, "xyz", true);
```

Then you'd just look up the type you're checking for a match to see if the values are equal (or if there's a null value in the tuple).

If you need to be able to determine *which* types are being matched by the string (and don't want to iterate over the known types), then obviously this approach wouldn't work...but you'd need to establish some sort of precedence rules as well...

UPDATE:
One approach would be to use SQL and add some indices (if you don't want to write your own B-tree based indices). Yeah, it's disk-based, but the table will probably be cached if you use refer to it a lot, and if you don't there's not really a reason to worry about performance.

A simpler idea would be to use sorted sets. Not very memory efficient, but might be fast enough depending on how your rules are set up. You would construct a set for each possible value for each field, which contains the type strings. For instance, you'd have a set where a="abc", which have two members, "type a string" and "type b string", and also a set for a=*, which would have a single member, "type m string".

If you were trying to to find the values that matched a string where a="abc", b="xxx", and c=true, you'd take the intersection of the a="abc" and a=* sets, intersect it with the union of b="xxx" and b=*, and then intersect that with the union of c=true and c=*. You would then have a set of values that matched your key.

It would run in O([a="abc"] + [a=*] + [b="xxx"] + [b=*] + [c=true] + [c=*]) = O(n)

Sure, it O(n) just to iterate over all rules to check for matches, but here we're drastically reducing the size of n.